# How do I capture the mouse when a Silverlight RepeatButton is depressed?

Tags: silverlight, events, repeatbutton, mousecapture

I have a `RepeatButton` on a `UserControl` that acts as the up button.  The control is a number spinner of sorts.  When the number value goes from 9 to 10 the up button is released because it moves out from under the mouse.  I know I can capture the mouse, but my `RepeatButton` is not giving me `MouseLeftButtonDown` events.  So how do I capture the mouse over the `RepeatButton` when it is depressed and release the capture when it is released? And should the `RepeatButton` give me `MouseLeftButtonDown` events?

**Edits:**

It would seem that the template content is stealing the button's `MouseLeftButtonDown` events. Is there anyway I can circumvent the button's content.  If I set `HitTestVisible` to false, the button itself becomes untouchable. I wish silverlight had `OnPreview` overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried utilising MouseLeftButtonUp instead to check if it can occur when the mouse button is released?

Comment: Yes I have, and it does not, but how does that help me capture the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with Windows 8/WinRT and found a workaround - you can bind something to the button's IsPressed property and when it gets set to false - it means the button/touch is up.